# Save stdout from win application launched with admin rights in non admin console

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have test c++ console application which require administrative rights and produce output to console using std::cout << "log"

I am launching this application from test.bat with following content
testconsoleapp.exe > test.log
EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

and test.bat was started by virtualbox
vboxmanage.exe guestcontrol .. run --wait-stdout --wait-stderr test.bat

And my test.log is empty when I am using function AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)

Current solution is to specify filename for console application and write to file instead of std::cout, but may be there is an easy way

Comment: So `testconsoleapp` is being elevated?  If I remember correctly, the elevation process breaks output redirection.  You'll need to run the batch file with elevated privileges too, or have it elevate itself.

Comment: Initially I start process via vboxmanage.exe, so I can't give admin permissions at start